How do I fire two functions off on button onClick?
I am creating a page within React that has a sidebar on the left and whatever button is clickedloads a different iFrame in on the right.
To handle this I was using:
const [page, setPage ] = useState("FirstFrame");  

and when it came to the button I was using:
onClick={() => setPage("FirstFrame")}> 

Problem is now, I have to add an active class to each button as they are clicked. Which I was using:
const handleClick = (index) => {
    setActiveButton(index); 
 };

and on the button:
onClick={() => handleClick(0)} className={activeButton ===0 ? 'activeBTN' : ''}

But I can't use two onClick here. How do I go about solving this?

...write one function that calls both the others? Have handleClick call setPage, or vice versa?

You can call the setPage and the setActiveButton setter functions in your handleClick event handler.
const handleClick = (index, currentFrame) => {
    setActiveButton(index); 
    setPage(currentFrame);
};

<button
 onClick={() => handleClick(0, "FirstFrame")} className={`${activeButton === 0 ? 'activeBTN' : ""} text-primary bg-blue-200`}>
   Text
</button>

''}


Thanks @Hamed
Helps so much.
Just one last question, sorry. I forgot to say that will I want to add activeBTN, I also want a regular btn class. But anytime I add it, it throws an error:
Example:
onClick={() => handleClick(0, "SecondFrame")} className={myBTN activeButton ===0 ? 'activeBTN' : ""}
(I am trying to add myBTN that does not change, only activeBTN)

I have just updated my answer to allow the addition of more classes. I used text primary and bg-blue-200 arbitrary class names. You can edit the classes to suit your need.
